# Fast Fourier Transform for Water surface simulation

Tags: opengl, c++

I want to implement water in my game and have already done it using the Gerstner equation, but the result is not too impressive, then searching the Internet I found an article about how someone made water using the Philips Spectrum equation and the fast Fourier transform, but I don't quite understand the process of getting final displacement map. I tried to use FFT on site with this image:

[image]

And got this result:

[image]

I don't understand how I can get a displacement map for the water surface from this whole thing, maybe someone has already encountered this and has some kind of implementation, I would be very grateful to get some piece of code or an article with a good description of the whole process.
I only found the following picture, that shows the process and results:

[image]

The above image came from [this article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/54924233175/).

Comment: Did you use FFT or an inverse FFT? The second image looks like what yoi'd get it you took a Fourier transform twice, instead of *undoing* the fourier transform to get from the frequency domain to the spatial domain.

Comment: I used fft. I'm already confused and don't understand what the result of ifft and fft should look like